# How to split using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a record

```
"Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead;
Information Technology (IT) > IT Management;
Information Technology (IT) > Network & System"
```

I am trying to get the data like:

```
IT Project Management / Team Lead
IT Management
Network & System
```

Can anybody give me a suggestion to get the solution please.
Thanks

Comment: What did you tried, so far?

Comment: How is that data stored?  Is it just a string?

Comment: thanks for quick reply.As I mentioned above that I have a string value "Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead;
Information Technology (IT) > IT Management;
Information Technology (IT) > Network & System" . I am trying to split the value in a string list like "IT Project Management / Team Lead"
"IT Management"
"Network & System"

Comment: string a = "Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead; Information Technology (IT) > IT Management; Information Technology (IT) > Network & System";
            string[] splitted = a.Split(';');
            foreach (string item in splitted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Substring(item.IndexOf(">")+1));
            }

Comment: thanks @NaveenBathina. I have also resolved and my answer is string val = "Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead; Information Technology (IT) > IT Management; Information Technology (IT) > Network & System"; 

            string[] newval21 = val.Split(';');
            List<string> words11 = new List<string>();

            foreach (string s in newval21)
            {
                var ss = s.Split('>');
                words11.Add(ss[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(ss[1]);
            }

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can split the string based on the ';' character.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

```
    char[] delimiterChars = { ';' };        
    string text = @"Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead; Information Technology (IT) > IT Management; Information Technology (IT) > Network & System";
    System.Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: i need the result like:  "IT Project Management / Team Lead", "IT Management" ,"Network & System" in list. But your solution gives the result like: "Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead",..where as I am trying to split "Information Technology (IT) >"

Comment: You should be able to remove the portion that you don't want to display after splitting (in the foreach loop).
    s.Remove("Information Technology (IT) > ");

Comment: @Trogdor.exactly but how to achieve this. I am struggling for 2 days.

Comment: You further need to split `s` to another string array using `>` as delimiter to get the second part

Comment: @only Use Trogdor's method above and further split `s` inside foreach loop using `string[] finalwords = s.Split(">"c);` and then access second part by refering `finalwords[1].Trim`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said 
    s = s.Remove("Information Technology (IT) > ");

Comment: thanks @Trogdor your answer make me the right way. I have resolved my problem and the answer is string val = "Information Technology (IT) > IT Project Management / Team Lead; Information Technology (IT) > IT Management; Information Technology (IT) > Network & System"; 

            string[] newval21 = val.Split(';');
            List<string> words11 = new List<string>();

            foreach (string s in newval21)
            {
                var ss = s.Split('>');
                words11.Add(ss[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(ss[1]);
            }

Comment: You're welcome. Please up-vote my answer if you can.  Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I've been given a temporary answer ban... I'm new so I'd appreciate the benefit of the doubt from the moderators / voters. I guess that I'll wait out the ban before contributing again??

Comment: Hello @Dave-Zych or other moderators.  Is there a way to unblock my ability to contribute to answers?  I don't see a way to "correct" previous answers.  Thanks.

Comment: @varocarbas can you please tell me why my answer ability is block with no way to "correct" the previous answers? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant blocked.